# What version of ECMAScript can we assume if we have web workers?

Tags: javascript, browser

We are creating a javascript client app that uses web workers. We will only run on browsers that support web workers.

What version of ECMAScript can we assume those browsers support? Do they all support version 5?

Answer (score 4):

Web Workers were pulled out of the ECMAScript 5 standard. Instead, they are currently defined in an [editors draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/workers/), which is not linked to a specific version of ECMAScript.

Basically, you can't assume a particular version.

If `typeof window.Worker === 'function'`, you can assume the browser has *some* Web Worker support; but be aware of the [perils of working with them](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=127990).

[caniuse.com shows the following level of support for Web Workers (at the time of writing...):](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers)

- IE >= 10.0
- Firefox >= 3.5
- Chrome >= 4
- Safari >= 4.0
- Opera >= 10.6

But again, I **strongly** recommend you [feature detect rather than browser sniff](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/).

Even if Web Workers *were* linked to a specific ECMAScript version, a browser never really *conforms* to a particular version as you might think. A browser might fully support one ECMASCript 5 feature, partially support another, have buggy support in another, whilst not support another at all.

Comment: We have 1 web worker so I'm not worried about the limits on how many. Bummer that they're not specifically tied. I'm hoping someone here has tested all and knows. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [Web Worker specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) offers the following definition: *'"JavaScript" is used to refer to ECMA262, rather than the official term ECMAScript, since the term JavaScript is more widely known,'* and proceeds to [link in the footnotes](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) to the latest edition of ECMA262: **5.1**.

Admittedly circuitous (and unreliable) as an answer…

Comment: I'm not sure I would trust that as a certainty for all browsers that implement web workers. But it is a good indicator that 5.1 could well be the minimum. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidThielen I wouldn't trust it either. I had interpreted your question to be more theoretical than one of implementation, as testing for the presence of the method, as Matt has suggested, is nearly always the preferred method for *actually detecting* support.

Comment: Oh we'll definitely test. What I want to avoid is we make use of ECMA5 and then refuse to run on a browser that has web worker support, because it does not have ECMA5 support. On the flip side, if all web worker implementation do have ECMA5 support, I want to make use of that.

Comment: @DavidThielen That last part is exactly what I figured you were going to use it for. Why not, right?